# 'Error: Expected' when creating switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab05a
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    String statement;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int vowela;
    int vowele;
    int voweli;
    int vowelo; 
    int vowelu;
    int nonvowel;

    int vowela = 0;
    int vowele = 0;
    int voweli = 0;
    int vowelo = 0;
    int vowelu = 0;

    statement = scan.nextString();
    statement = statement.toLowerCase();

    for (int i = 0; i <= statement.length(); count++)
    {
      char c = examplestring.charAt(i);
      if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
        switch (c)
      {
        case 'a':
          vowela += 1;
          break;
        case 'e':
          vowele += 1;
          break;
        case 'i';
          voweli += 1;
          break;
        case 'o';
          vowelo += 1;
          break;
        case 'u';
          vowelu += 1;
          break;
      }
      else
        nonvowel +=1;
    }
      System.out.prinln("a: " + vowela);
      System.out.prinln("e: " + vowele);
      System.out.prinln("i: " + voweli);
      System.out.prinln("o: " + vowelo);
      System.out.prinln("u: " + vowelu);
      System.out.prinln("nonvowel: " + novowel);
  }
}
```

I thought of doing it this way:

- First I create a `for` loop to iterate through every character of String statement.
- Then I put an `if` statement in the for loop that checks if `c`(declared as `statement.charAt(i)`) is a vowel.
- If c is a vowel I use a switch to increase the count for that particular vowel by one and then break.
- If `c` is not a vowel, it gets added to the count of consonants.
- After the for loop is done it prints the count of each character.

---

The switch is where I am having problems. Case `'a'` and case `'e'` have cause no errors, but cases `'i'` through `'u'` cause an error(`'Error: : Expected'`).
I don't understand what this means or why, as cases `'i'` through `'u'` are written the same way as cases `'a'` and `'e'`. Can someone help me out?

```
3 errors found:
[line: 38] Error: : expected
[line: 41] Error: : expected
[line: 44] Error: : expected
```

Sorry if this post is poorly formatted I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45199020/edit) and [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) instead.

Comment: `statement = scan.nextString().toLowerCase();` should be `statement = scan.next().toLowerCase();`

Comment: Sorry I am trying to edit it and fix the format but I'm having trouble with it.

Comment: Can you post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors in your code, I have modified it (posted at the bottom) and pointed out some of your mistakes:

1. Change `statement = scan.nextString().toLowerCase();` to `statement = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();`
2. > I don't understand what this means or why, as cases 'i' through 'u' are written the same way as cases 'a' and 'e'.

Your switch is wrong because cases `i`, `o`, and `u` have a semi-colon(`;`) instead of a colon(`:`). Just that small difference is causing the error there. Change your `switch` statement to this:

```
    switch(c) {
        case 'a':
            vowela++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            vowele++
            break;
        case 'i':
            voweli++
            break;
        case 'o':
            vowelo++
            break;
        case 'u':
            vowelu++;
            break;
    }
```

Here's your modified code. Now it is correct, and it works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab05a {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String statement;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int vowela = 0;
        int vowele = 0;
        int voweli = 0;
        int vowelo = 0;
        int vowelu = 0;
        int nonvowel = 0;
        statement = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < statement.length(); i++) {
            char c = statement.charAt(i);
            switch (c) {
                case 'a':
                    vowela++;
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    vowele++;
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    voweli++;
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    vowelo++;
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    vowelu++;
                    break;
                default:
                    nonvowel++;
                    break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("a: " + vowela);
        System.out.println("e: " + vowele);
        System.out.println("i: " + voweli);
        System.out.println("o: " + vowelo);
        System.out.println("u: " + vowelu);
        System.out.println("nonvowel: " + nonvowel);
    }
}
```

You may have noticed some changes such as removing the `if` statement that checks for a vowel. Rather than doing all of that, I just added a default case. If none of the other conditions are true, than whatever is in the `default` case is executed. I also initialized your variables `vowela`, `vowele`, `voweli`, etc., and rather than doing `vowela += 1` I just changed it to `vowela++`, which produces the same effect(same with the other letters).